# Is it okay to ask many questions?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, policy

I ask a lot of questions, but also try to answer some.
is it okay to ask many questions?  I try researching first and then asking them.

Answer (score 14):

It's OK to ask many *good* questions. But good questions require lots of thought.

This is not just a smart-ass one-liner response. It is really, really difficult to ask good questions. I just went back and looked at mine and found;

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245196/c-urban-myths - original question  wasn't clear, so I got lots of noise
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006726/which-would-you-prefer-to-have-to-maintain - far too argumentative
- [In C++, if throw is an expression, what is its type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212978/in-c-if-throw-is-an-expression-what-is-its-type) - complete cluelessness on my part regarding what language feature I was actually asking about
- [Boost considered harmful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/569198/boost-considered-harmful) - doesn't even ask  a question!

It is sad to note that these bad questions have many more upvotes than my few clear, concise, technical questions :-(

Comment: can you comment on overall quality of my questions?

Comment: @aaa Well, your last one should have said why you were interested in alignment, for example.

Comment: okay, point taken.  sometimes I forget things relevant to me may not he obvious to other people

Comment: The answer I have a gold badge for is not technical at all, and arguably doesn't belong on the site.  Not that I'm returning the badge, you understand.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to learn, asking questions can be quite helpful. Especially on sites like S[OFU]. There is quite the community here, and a massive collective knowledge. I've learned plenty just by lurking on these sites.

It is important to ask questions that can be answered. Provide necessary details, be specific, and you'll probably get helpful responses in short order.