# Is it okay to ask multiple homework questions

Tags: support, homework

> Very very possible this question is duplicate with this question:
>   [Is it okay to ask many questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48514/is-it-okay-to-ask-many-questions)

The question is almost fit with my condition, but I'm still hesitating.

I know this question is appears too much in this forum, but please look these conditions.

**First**, I'm not a native English speaker. I've seen this question answered with too much technical words and it doesn't simply answers the question yes or no, so I always don't get the point from the answer itself.

**Second**, how about an user asking many homework questions, but he/she also provided his/her approach to answer? It's like you solve all problems, post the problems with your approaches one-by-one to the forum and asking "Is my approaches right?"

**Third**, with the **Second** condition, I'm worry that the forum moderator/OP will answer like "Why you ask too much" or something like that.

I'm okay if this question is closed, but please answer with your kindness (or clarification).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I start with some nit-picking. We are [**not** a forum](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92110/158100).

This answer is generic. Certain communities might feel different.

The sites require everyone to post in the English language (except a few language specific sites). To ask your question with the correct wording, understandable for all users, needs more effort than native speakers (Google translate is a tool for that not a solution). When you get an answer that has not understandable phrases in it, you can always ask in comments if you understood certain phrases/words correctly, using your own words. That should signal the answerer that their verbiage needs work. Keep in mind that the answerer might have mis-interpreted your question based on your translation/choose of words, edit your question if that is the case. As a last resort make clear you're not a native speaker.

In general *good* questions are welcome. it doesn't matter if they are homework or not. What a good question is depends but is described in the [help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help) and [ask](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) of each site. Some communities are very open for homework, some are somewhat reluctant to accept them. If you **show** what you have researched (include links and references), the steps/assumptions you made, outcome, expected outcome and what you actually want to get answered it doesn't matter if it is homework. But don't expect the users to do your (home)work.

New users can only ask a [limited number of questions per day](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide) (6 per day or 50 per 30 days). If you are able to ask that many questions and still believe they are well researched, proper stated you are either a genius or have to re-read my post. Again, if you stay within the boundaries of the site you can ask many questions. If you are in doubt, use the quality checklists available on many meta's, or ask on meta if you are unsure if your question will be good enough / is on-topic. If you receive down votes or close votes on your question, step back and assume something is wrong with your post. Start a meta-post or ask in [Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/) for some guidance.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for answering! This answer is most understandable than any question (related to homework) I've seen. Gratefully, my English skill is moderate and increasing every day every time I come to English StackExchange.

Comment: For the paragraph "In general good questions are welcome", I indeed this. I feel every community has different sense to asking. I mean like most questions that included detail research (question that doesn't have one-shot answer), answered with short-and-low-quality answer. Maybe most people in the community itself don't like too complicated question and thinking like "this site is not for conducting research". That's why too many questions get Bounce.

Comment: In the other community, most short questions replied by long and intuitive answer, which is making good so the asker not only get answer, but plus deep concept and very-well understanding.